# How to access XML SAML tab from Chrome developer tools?

Tags: testng, saml

I want to access SAML tab of Chrome dev tool for my selenium project. I tried to use `LoggingPreferences`, but it has limited set of `LogTypes` and none of the existing `LogType` is working here. Is there any way to access the data of this tab?

Screenshot of the tab
[SAML Browser dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP779.png)